In local storage, I see the key "debug" with the value " honey:core-sdk:*", what is this?

I found a "honey-core" npm package that I never intentionally installed. I uninstalled it through the CLI, no errors or anything, but that is still showing up in local storage. Does anybody know what this is and how to get rid of it? I can right click and delete it, but it comes back when I refresh.
EDIT: It was an extension I have in chrome. I deleted it and that fixed the problem!

Right click it and hit "Delete"

I did that, but when I refresh it comes back. I'll edit my question to show that.

local storage is scoped to you project/site.  Check your project for that dependency.

When you say "I found a "honey-core" npm package that I never intentionally installed" are you sure this isn't a dependency of something you did install intentionally? You can run npm ls --all to see a tree of what might be using that as a dependency.

@ScottZ I searched package.json and package-lock.json and found nothing with 'debug' or 'honey.' Same when I ran npm ls --all

Your package.json is just a manifest of what your app needs to run. Everything you mention there will have its own package.json which will be what it in turn needs to run. Running npm install, very simply put, works out what it needs to install from all of the files here based on what they say they need to run, which is what your node_modules folder is. The code that is actually putting executing localStorage.setItem when you run your app will be in a package in the node_modules folder.

@Alex weird. I can't find any trace of this in node_modules either. I guess I'll just have to write some code to ignore that, because I'm not sure what else to do from here. I appreciate your help!

It will almost certainly have no discernible effect on your app and might not even be added when your app is deployed so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Local storage is created by client-side code, node.js is server-side. So you need to search the client code to see where this is coming from.

The Honey Framework is an open-source toolkit for traders to develop and implement custom order types & trading strategies on the Bitfinex cryptocurrency exchange.
